# Processes in Java- Do they work concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I am executing another java program through a Process object.
This takes some time to complete. In the mean time, will the parent program continue running or will it be on hold, to wait for the child process to stop?

I know that two threads can run in parallel, can a thread be used to execute this other program?

Please let me know if you need any more details, if this became too abstract.

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: Yes, I am trying it as well. But thought of asking you all once..

Comment: Helpful page regarding threads/processes that should answer your question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

Comment: Doing the opposite of what you suggest is relatively hard so if you have ever run two programs at once on a machine, you should be able to answer this question yourself. Have you ever run two independent programs at once and seen one stop while the other was running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will execute separately unless you either block waiting for data from the other process (e.g. calling `Process.getInputStream()` and then reading from it), or call [`Process.waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). The second process has its own threads - these are *not* the threads of the process that happens to start the second process.

Of course, it's possible that both processes will end up dealing with the same resource and have to cooperate in that sense - but in general, using multiple processes is a separation level up from threads. (It's relatively tricky to get processes to access the same memory, to get their threads to coordinate with each other, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The two processes are independent and run in parallel. The parent can wait for the child to terminate calling the waitFor method in the Process class.